# Wordpress Images upload error "Failed to write file to disk."

Tags: wordpress, image, file-upload, permissions

I am having following error:

Failed to write file to disk.

When trying to add featured image or add media, image progress bar completes with error and no image is uploading.

Have changed permission of uploads directory to: 777

but no luck.

Comment: You should change permission for subdirectories as well.

Comment: Yes I did it using recursive check

Answer (score 0):

There are three common causes :

1. upload directory permissions - not the case here
2. the server's hard drive is full / your quota has been exceeded
3. the server's tmp folder is full

references :

[How to Fix "Upload:Failed to Write File to Disk" Error in WordPress](http://www.beginwp.com/fix-failed-to-write-file-to-disk-error-in-wordpress/)

[WordPress Error : Failed to write file to disk - InMotion Hosting](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/failed-to-write-to-disk)